# Return object realm not accessible

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having problems with an object that returns me in Realm, the strange thing is that if I printo console the object if I start it well but however if I try to access its value it tells me that it is empty.

The structure of the object is as follows:

```
class Favourite : Object {
    var character : Character!
}
```

1. I create an object and add it to the DB

   ```
   let fav = Favourite()
   fav.character = character
   FavouriteDao.sharedInstance.addFavourite(characterFavourite: fav)
   ```
2. Get all objects of favorite type

   func getAllFavourites() -> Results {
        return realm.objects(Favourite.self)
    }
3. When I get the item and do a print

   ```
   Favourite {
   character = Character {
       name = Spider-Man;
       descriptionC = Bitten by a radioactive spider, high school student Peter Parker gained the speed, strength and powers of a spider. Adopting the name Spider-Man, Peter hoped to start a career using his new abilities. Taught that with great power comes great responsibility, Spidey has vowed to use his powers to help people.;
       thumbnail = Thumbnail {
           id = 815D93D0-C116-4267-978C-9E47C0074D0D;
           path = http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/3/50/526548a343e4b;
           extensionImage = jpg;
       };
   };
   ```
4. If I try to access the character element it tells me that it is **nil**

Somebody manages to understand because if I make a print of the favorite object it shows me that there is inside a character object but nevertheless if I try to accede to it it says that it does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is totally wrong from the very beginning. You should read the realm docs first. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started

For example.

```
class Favourite : Object {
    var character : Character!
}
```

is not something you should do in Realm.

Assuming your `Character` is well-defined, the code should be `dynamic var character : Character? = nil` at least.

Comment: Yes , the problem is dynamic I thought what if the property is object is not required the dynamic , ok thanks.

Comment: `dynamic` means the variable is working in `Objective-C` dynamic way. With `dynamic`, the getter and setter are injected, doing extras things, by the database provider, which is Realm here. So all properties you want in Realm should begin with `dynamic`, unless Realm explicitly not to, like `List<T>` . If you don't use `dynamic`, the `var character ` is just a non-Realm property and won't save to Realm at all.